# Move sprite in the direction of the value from the rotation?

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I'm new to XNA and I'm building an Asteroids game. I have some problems to get my spaceship to move forward in the direction I want. When I press the arrow up key, I want the engine to start and move the space ship in the same directions as the rotation of the spaceship? Help is preciated! I add the subclass that is my spaceship. The Draw method and its variables are in the main class. I'm not sure what to have in the EngineOn method?

```
 class Spaceship: GameObject
{

    // Konstruktor
    public Spaceship(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position): base(texture, position)
    {

    }

    public override void Update()
    {
        direction = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(rotation), (float)Math.Sin(rotation));
        position += direction * speed;  //position = position + direction
        //base.Update();
    }

    // Metod som beräknar rymdskeppets färd i riktningen
    public void EngineOn()
    {
        Update();
    }

    // Metod som beräknar rymdskeppets rotation motsols
    public void RotateLeft()
    {
        rotation -= rotationSpeed;
    }

    // Metod som beräknar rymdskeppets rotation medsols
    public void RotateRight()
    {
        rotation += rotationSpeed;
    }

    // Metod som beräknar bana för avlossade skott
    public void Fire()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: And your problem is? Ship does not move, or move in wrong direction, or what?

Comment: The ship don't move forward in it's direction. It can rotate.

Comment: and speed property in different that 0? ;)

Comment: Does your ship move at all? Like trying to hardcode the position (Position.X += 0.5f) etc?

Comment: Show your drawing code, where you actually use rotation and position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void EngineOn()
{
    speed = 20;
}
public void EngineOff()
{
    speed = 0;
}
```

P.S. Your speed is CPU is dependent, multiply your speed on deltaTime

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    direction = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(rotation), (float)Math.Sin(rotation));
    position += direction * speed * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still not moving forward!? Strange, what could I have done wrong?

Comment: If it moves forward your direction is probably (0, 1). Sin and Cos in Formula are right. May be rotation is always 0? Just force direction to be for example (0.4, 0.6) and see weather Ship still moves in other direction.

Comment: It is NOT moving at any direction! It only rotate at the same position.

Comment: show your Draw Method of GameObject. Is it something like (spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White))?

Comment: "P.S. Your speed is CPU is dependent, multiply your speed on deltaTime" No its not unless you specifically disable the XNA timestep which is enabled by default.

Comment: spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, null, Color.White, rotation, origin, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0f); But since this method is used and inherit by other objects that works fine, the problem must be somewhere else. I have to check my code again. I will return. Thanks for now!

Comment: The problem was that I had missed to call the Update method!